# Showing map in Grass Layer Manager/Map Display via Python

Tags: python, grass-gis, display

I've created some raster(tif) maps using Grass libraries in Python. I want to opem them automatically in Grass GIS Map Display or Layer Manager after creation. I don't want to use GUI for this. What commands I need to use for this?

I'm using GRASS GIS 6.5.svn over Windows 7.

Thansk in advance..

Answer (score 1):

In GRASS 7 there is a new command line driven monitor called "wx0" (also wx1, ...). It may be extended (maybe already possible, I did not try) to support direct Python control since it is written in Python and wxPython.

You can install GRASS 7 in parallel to your existing GRASS 6 installation.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and then inform you about situation.